# Render PayPal SmartButton in aspx page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, paypal

Attempting to render a PayPal smartbutton in asp View tag using .net 3.5. Here's a sample of the code:

[image]

The client_id and PayPal button are included in the actual code.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: id of div must match the selector passed to .render() , and P-XX must be a valid plan_id created using that client-id

Comment: PayPal has an [online tool](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart) to generate the code for the button.

Comment: A valid plan id has been included, as well. I forgot to mention it in the initial post. So, the plan id has been added to both the div tag and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve by calling JS code from code-behind, e.g.:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "ShowButton", "loadButton();", True)
```